# Rust member of struct containing member that references another member of that struct

Tags: rust, ownership

Here is my situation:
I have a structure named X. X contains a member of type Y that contains a reference to Z. Z is also a member of X. As shown in this code

```rust
struct X<'a> {
    y: Y<'a>,
    z: Z
}

struct Y<'a> {
    z: &'a Z
}

struct Z;

impl<'a> X<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> X<'a> {
        ???
    }
}
```

I am confused about how to create a function that creates X. I've tried doing it in the following way:

```rust
impl<'a> X<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> X<'a> {
        let z = Z{};
        
        let y = Y { z: &z };
        
        X {
            y, z
        }
    }
}
```

But obviously, it won't work since z is local. I know there is a way of doing it with Rc but I need both X and Y to be able to modify Z and Rc is not mutable and probably doesn't model ownership properly since X shouldn't own Z.

Is there a way to do it using idiomatic Rust or just I completely reevaluate my design, and if so how do I structure it?